# Isolating punctuation from words in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, punctuation

I am trying to isolate *not remove* punctuation from words in an array.

For example, this array contains words with punctuation in them:

```
let words = ["hello", "world!!"]
```

The following code performs the isolation of *one* of the punctuation marks.

```
for i in 0..<words.count {          
    if let range = words[i].rangeOfCharacter(from: .punctuationCharacters) {
        words.insert(words[i].substring(with: range), at: i+1)
        words[i].replaceSubrange(range, with: "")
    }
}
```

And as a result the `words` array becomes:

```
["hello", "world!", "!"]
```

However, I would like the function to isolate each punctuation mark individually instead of one at a time like it does now:

```
["hello", "world", "!", "!"]
```

As of current, I have tried iterating through the characters of the string and testing them against `CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters`, but that feels inefficient and *clunky*.

How can I achieve this in a Swift-y fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a Swifty fashion way of doing it, but if your array of words is consistent you can do as follow:

```
let words = ["hello", "world!!"]
var res: [String] = []
for word in words {
    res += word.components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters).filter{!$0.isEmpty}
    res += word.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.inverted).filter{!$0.isEmpty}.joined().characters.map{String($0)}
}
print(res)   // ["hello", "world", "!", "!"]
```